# std::make_pair C++11 + VS2013=compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have such codee:

```
struct Foo {
  unsigned attr : 7;

  std::pair<char *, unsigned> f() {
      char *ch = nullptr;
      return std::make_pair(ch, static_cast<unsigned>(attr));
  }
};
```

MSVS2013 give me something like this error:

> can not convert 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int&'

While gcc 4.8 and clang 3.3 compile such code without errors.

Is this MSVS compiler bug? If so, where I should report it?

Comment: Does using `std::make_pair<char *, unsigned>` help?

Comment: No, only std::pair<> instead of std::make_pair helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiles and works just fine in VS2010. Must be a bug. Report it to Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks, submit bug report here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797715/std-make-pair-c-11-vs-2013